# Why does Facebook Share Pull the Wrong Thumbnail?

Tags: html, facebook, facebook-sharer

I have a quick question, hopefully someone can help me. I recently took a microsite live for a client and everything went smoothly except for a facebook integration piece. When a user attempts to Share the site, the thumbnail pulled for the share reflects the logo from the main site, not the microsite. I am baffled because this logo can be found nowhere on the page. Additionally, I have included the requisite meta information in the header of the document
`<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.rethinkyourdrinknow.com/images/ryd/logo2.png" />` 
but for some reason it still pulls the other image. Does anyone have more experience with Facebook share that could possibly lend a hand?

Thanks,
Jamey

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using the Facebook Linting tool (now the debugger)

http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug

Enter the URL of your microsite, the tool should tell you whats going on.

Comment: Even their debug tool has conflicting information. `og:image` shows different from their `Here's what it looks like when shared` section.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that OGP only likes thumbnails which dimensions are the same or more than 200px. If you upload an image and set it as thumbnail (which dimensions are, by WP default, 150x150 pixels) you're going to get an error message if you run your post's link into the FB debugger like this:

Open Graph Warnings That Should Be Fixed

```
Small og:image: All the images referenced by og:image should be at least 200px in both dimensions. Please check all the images with tag og:image in the given url and ensure that it meets the recommended specification.
```

So I manually enlarged an image into one of my previous posts to the actual 200x200 pixel size and tadadah!!! Facebook shares the proper link and proper image also from WP homepage or single post.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on @Andy's answer, you can certainly use the Debugger tool to see how facebook views your URL.  It will tell you exactly what `og:tags` are missing/malformed.
One thing to note is that facebook does some caching on `og:tags` of URL's that have been shared; but using the Debugger tool will refresh facebooks caching of your URL.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with LinkedIn. I added `<meta property="og:image" content="https:` and so on to my index.html, but LinkedIn kept pulling the wrong picture because it had already cached my site.

Here's the trick to force the embedding app (LinkedIn, Facebook, etc.) to treat your website as never cached before and therefore read it completely from scratch, including your new `og:image`.

When you input your full link to the social media site, add `?01` at the very end of it. E.g. `https://example.com?01` or `https://example.com/my_project/?01`

Just tried it and it worked like magic!